# Por que minha função não está alterando o background como esperado?

Tags: react

Estou tentando mudar a transparência do meu `header` baseado no scroll da tela. Para tanto, criei um `eventListener` de `scroll` que dispara a seguinte função:

```
function solidHeader(){
    if (document.getElementById('crossfade').getBoundingClientRect().bottom < 60) {
        setTypeBackground('solid')
    } else {
        setTypeBackground('transparent')
    }
}
```

O objetivo é que, quando o `bottom` da `<div id="crossfade" />` tocar no `bottom` do `header`, o que acontece quando a `<div id="crossfade" />` está a 60px do topo da página, a função mude o estado de `typeBackground` para `'solid'`. Com isso, é esperado que o `useEffect`:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', solidHeader)
useEffect(() => {
    /* A tag de id="Card" é o header */
    document.getElementById('Card').style.backgroundColor = typeBackground
}, [typeBackground])
```

dispare, alterando a propriedade `backgroundColor` do `header` para `'solid'`. Mas isso não acontece. Por quê?

Talvez seja importante mencionar que essa função está sendo implementada num componente irmão do `header`:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div id="super-container">
            <AuthProvider>
                /* Esse é o header que quero alterar: */
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    /* esse é o componente que monitora o scroll e tenta alterar a propriedade: */
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/servicos" component={Servicos} />
                    <Route path="/teste" component={AreaCliente} />
                </Switch>
            </AuthProvider>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, confesso que não entendi ao certo o seu problema, mas levando em consideração esse trecho abaixo, talvez eu possa ajudar...

> Estou tentando mudar a transparência do meu header baseado no scroll
> da tela.

Criei um exemplo simples que atende esse enunciado, talvez não seja exatamente o que você precisa, mas você pode facilmente o modificar para atender a sua necessidade.

https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-8sxdp

Comment: Bruno, agradecido pela boa vontade de tentar ajudar. Mas se você não entendeu a pergunta, é sinal de que não deveria estar respondendo. Sua resposta parece caber muito mais num comentário. Note que, apesar de o seu código resolver o problema, ele não responde a pergunta. Tendo dito isso, seu código foi útil pra eu tentar adotar outra abordagem de monitoramento de scroll. A que eu estava usando era mto pesada

Comment: Olá, obrigado pelo feedback, postei uma resposta pois sou novo no stackOverflow, e por isso, ainda não posso comentar em perguntas.